# In Oracle performance monitoring why does Scheduler activity goes up

Tags: performance, oracle, scheduler

What does scheduler mean in Oracle?
Is it connection scheduling or query scheduling or the query plan execution scheduling or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 10g and above, the term "scheduler" usually refers to the processes that are running under the new Oracle job scheduler that was introduced in that release.  Prior to 10g, there was a less functional scheduler and jobs that were running under that were usually referred to as "dbms jobs" because the API used to manage them was the PL/SQL built-in package DBMS_JOB.

Other info:

- Both types of scheduled jobs exist as
  of the 11g release - the API for the
  new jobs is DBMS_SCHEDULER
- DBMS_SCHEDULER adds several important
  enhancements such as the ability to
  run targets other than PL/SQL blocks,
  logging, interfaces to maintenance
  windows, and friendlier specification
  of the time intervals between
  executions
- A standard install of Enterprise
  Edition will create several
  DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs out of the box -
  probably the only one you'll ever
  need to modify/replace/reschedule is
  the job that computes statistics for
  the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Our scheduler seems to be contributing to lots of throughput activity during peak hours and we are going to disable it. Any thoughts on implications?

Comment: How did you determine that it is contributing to the throughput?  Can you isolate the activity to a specific job?

Comment: Yes, some specific queries (bulk inserts and huge select-joins) seem to increase the contribution of scheduler in the performance graphs.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding - is this related to a specific system scheduler job (for example, ORA$AUTOTASK_CLEAN )?  If so, you could reschedule it to a quieter period for the application.

Comment: @Monis Iqbal, first you have to know what kind of jobs are scheduled in your database before you can decide to disable them. Maybe you can run them during non-peak hours?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I suspect you mean the scheduler than runs jobs at certain times.  (It used to be called/accessed via DBMS_JOB if that rings any bells?)

I would guess that the Performance Monitor schedules regular jobs to look at query statistics etc, hence the increase in activity.

Comment: jobs to look at query statistics... I would change that into: jobs to gather statistics.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be that normal queries are controlled by resource manager. In that case you see waits for scheduler in grid control, without having run a single scheduled job.

best regards,
[Ronald](http://ronr.blogspot.com)